# How to submit the value of an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a math game that works partially. What I need to have happen is to take the values of the divs (one is x and the other is y), type in the answer of those two multiplied, be able to submit it and refresh to solve another.
Any help would be much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/justinw001/Mttw6/11/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        score = 0;
        var number = document.getElementById('inputElement').value;
        questionAmount = number;

        for(i = 0; i < questionAmount; i++) {
            var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);
            var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13);

            $('#input1').text(x);
            $('#input2').text(y);

            <!-- question = prompt('What is ' + x + ' * ' + y + ' = ?'); -->
            question = document.getElementById('answer').value;

            if(question == null || isNaN(question)) {
                break;
            }
            if(question == x * y) {
                score++;
            }
        }

        alert('You got ' + score + ' out of ' + questionAmount + ' correct.');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Well, you didn't exactly state what the problem is, but from what I can see here, the `<!-- -->` HTML comment tags don't belong there. You probably meant the JavaScript comment syntax `//`.

Comment: I should have specified a little more, I don't want the page to refresh I want the problem to change using a submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind the process with your buttons. Clicking the left button, produce the questions.
And Clicking the right one, verify the answer.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7m7Q6/)

```
    var score = 0;
    var questions = [];
    // Generate questions
    $('#gen').click(function () {
        score = 0;
        questions = [];
        var questionAmount = parseInt($('#inputElement').val(), 10);
        for (var i = 0; i < questionAmount; i++) {
            var q = {
                x: Math.floor(Math.random() * 13),
                y: Math.floor(Math.random() * 13)
            };
            questions.push(q);
        }
        nextQuest(questions.pop());
    });
    // Verify the answer
    $('#sub').click(function () {
        var ans, x, y;
        if (questions.length >= 0) {
            ans = parseInt($('#answer').val(), 10);
            x = parseInt($('#input1').text(), 10);
            y = parseInt($('#input2').text(), 10);
            if (ans === x * y) {
                score++;
                nextQuest(questions.pop());
            } else {
                alert('err');
            }
        }
    });
    var nextQuest = function (q) {
        if (q) {
            $('#input1').text(q.x);
            $('#input2').text(q.y);
            $('#answer').val('');
            $('#inputElement').val(questions.length);
        } else {
            $('#input1, #input2').text('');
            $('#answer, #inputElement').val('');
            alert(score);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the help. I had to edit a couple things, but you definitely made my it a lot easier!